# Gradle build and deploy specific buildtype

Tags: android, deployment, build, gradle

I want to build my gradle project with a certain buildtype and deploy it on device with a single command.

My build.gradle is setup for multiple buildtypes such as live and release.

I worked with maven before and i look for an equivalent of:

`mvn clean install -P release android:deploy android:run`

Comment: you should try `gradlew clean installRelease` or just use AndroidStudio, click Run and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the command to build and deploy through a specified BuildType. ( Thank you Varun! )

```
gradle installProfilename
```

Where **Profilename** of course would be the name of the BuildType specified in build.gradle

***Example.:***

```
gradle installRelease
```

Would build with the release profile:

```
buildTypes {

    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebugBuild false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.main
        . . . 
    }
```

**Addition.:**

Gradle can show you what tasks are available.:

```
gradle tasks
```

Comment: would it be possible to run a specific build and attach the debugger ?

Comment: @elgui Have a look at this blog article: http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2013/09/10/gradle-tip-attaching-a-debugger/