# IntelliJ+Gradle+Android. switch between Debug and Release buildtypes

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to run or debug in real device by switching two buildtypes in IntelliJ 14 as in VisualStudio.

[Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312737/361100) said to execute `installRelease` but only `installDebug` is appeared in my gradle android task, and I failed to run `gradlew installRelease` because the task is not exist.

The error message is given as below. pretty expected.

`Task 'installRelease' not found in root project 'u2020'. Some candidates are: 'uninstallRelease'.`

The build.gradle is as below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.2'
    }
}

// Manifest version information!
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 0 // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
debugCompile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit-mock:1.8.0'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.0'
debugCompile 'com.jakewharton.madge:madge:1.1.1'
debugCompile 'com.jakewharton.scalpel:scalpel:1.1.1'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.3'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.23.0'

compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.3'
}

def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
def buildTime = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

def isTravis = "true".equals(System.getenv("TRAVIS"))
def preDexEnabled = "true".equals(System.getProperty("pre-dex", "true"))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    dexOptions {
        // Skip pre-dexing when running on Travis CI or when disabled via -Dpre-dex=false.
        preDexLibraries = preDexEnabled && !isTravis
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.bapul.demo.u2020"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21

        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime}\""
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
            versionNameSuffix '-dev'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

The original code is from JakeWharton's demo app and gradle file can be found at here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/master/build.gradle

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these line in build.gradle of the app module

```
buildTypes {       
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And in signingConfigs below code if you wish to provide release keystore for the app.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("../../alphakeystore.jks")
        storePassword "123456"
        keyAlias "MyApp"
        keyPassword "123456"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added two buildTypes in build.gradle file, but still unable to switch them in IntelliJ. It only provides assembleRelease, assembleDebug to generate each apk. I'd like to deploy and run(+debugging) directly.